# If $aH=bH \implies Ha=Hb$ for a subgroup H having *finite index*, then $gH=Hg$ for all $g \in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Problem 2.5.9 of Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* asks us to prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ such that $Ha \not = Hb \implies aH \not = bH$, then $gHg^{-1} \subset H$ for all $g \in G$, which is equivalent to $gH \subset Hg.$ Suppose I have proved this (this result is of course true). I want to prove more, namely that, under the same premise, $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$. I think I can prove it **if I further assume that the index of $H$ in $G$ is finite**. Is this true? And if so, **is this additional hypothesis necessary** as well as sufficient? I.e. can you give an example of a subgroup $H$ of *infinite* index such that $aH \subset Ha$ but not vice versa? Thanks in advance. [DISCLAIMER: I am not yet familiar with normal subgroups]

Here's my attempt at a **proof**:

Suppose that $|G:H|=n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that  $aH \subset Ha$ for all $a \in G$. Now, suppose that there is an element $x$ such that $x \in Ha$ but $x \not \in aH$. Then $x$ must be contained in a different left coset, say $bH$, because the left cosets form a partition of $G$. Then, by our hypothesis, $x \in Hb$, which implies $Hb = Ha$, because the right cosets form a partition of $G$ as well. So far we have shown that $aH, bH \subset Ha=Hb$. But now we can prove that there are more left cosets than right ones! In fact, the remaining $n-1$ right cosets distinct from $Ha$ must contain at least one left coset, by our hypothesis, but $Ha$ contains two left cosets. So there are at least $n+1$ left cosets, a contradiction. Therefore $aH=Ha. \square$

Comment: Compare with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/224943/if-ah-bh-implies-ha-hb-then-aha-1-h-for-all-a-in-g) and its answers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The answers in your linked question only prove $gHg^{-1} \subset H$ and not equality. So I don't think they address the OP’s problem.

Comment: @Claudius This is not true. They prove equality, e.g., see Deven's answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, Deven *claims* to have shown $gHg^{-1} =H$. But what he really did was to prove $gHg^{-1} \subset H$. At least, I don't see how he proved the other inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof seems correct to me.

In fact, you can remove the finite index hypothesis. If $gHg^{-1} \subset H$ for all $g\in G$, then for each $g\in G$ you also have
$$
H = g^{-1}(gHg^{-1})g \subset g^{-1}Hg = g^{-1}H(g^{-1})^{-1} \subset H,
$$
so we must have equality throughout, i. e. $H = g^{-1}Hg$ (for each $g\in G$).

More generally, for any subgroup $H$ of $G$ the following holds: the set $N:= \{ g\in G \mid gHg^{-1}\subset H\}$ is a *subgroup* of $G$ if and only if $gHg^{-1} = H$ for all $g\in N$. (In that case $N$ is the *normalizer of $H$ in $G$*.)

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. Now I feel stupid for not having come up with that immediately! But why would Herstein keep this result from the reader and only ask to prove one inclusion? And what about this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217601/aha-1-subset-h-without-aha-1-h in which there seems to be a counterexample?

Comment: In the [answer of Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217622/218931) the set $\{g\in G\mid gHg^{-1} \subset H\}$ is not stable under inversion, hence not a group. It is only closed under composition.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any additional hypotheses. Multiplying both sides by $g^{-1}$ on the left and $g$ on the right yields

$$gHg^{-1} \subset H \implies H \subset g^{-1}Hg$$

Since this is true for all $g \in G$, we can substitute $g$ for $g^{-1}$, concluding

$$gHg^{-1} \subset H \subset gHg^{-1}$$

$$H = gHg^{-1}$$

This is equivalent to

$$gH = Hg$$